# Reference from one .js file to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use javascript bookmarklet with reference to extern path

```
javascript:(function(){var s = document.createElement('script');s.src = 'http://192.168.0.100/my.js';document.body.appendChild(s);})();
```

How I can create reference to jQuery.js file that is located in the same directory that my.js file?

Can I attah css file to this files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javascript:(function(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'http://192.168.0.100/my.js';
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    // Additional js file
    s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = '<jQuery location goes here>';
    document.body.appendChild(s);
    // CSS file
    s = document.createElement('link');
    s.rel = "stylesheet";
    s.href = "<location goes here>";
    s.type = "text/css";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the same code as you did for `my.js`:

```
javascript: (function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'http://192.168.0.100/my.js';
    document.body.appendChild(s);

    var s2 = document.createElement('script');
    s2.src = 'http://192.168.0.100/jquery.js';
    document.body.appendChild(s2);

    var l = document.createElement('link');
    l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = 'http://192.168.0.100/foo.css';
    l.type = 'text/css';
    document.body.appendChild(l);
})();
```

Comment: What about adding resources to ``document.head`` instead..?

Comment: document.head isn't widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might be quite an overkill for your specific requirement, but I'd like to point out the existence of [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) too , as it might be of interest for people finding this question later.

Briefly, what it does is to provide some facilities for dynamically loading resources in the page, supporting dependencies and namespacing (although you'll still have to wrap your modules so that they don't clog the global namespace).

This way, you can also easily manage dependencies, etc. even in (quite large) applications.