# Bookmarklet, behavior differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made .js bookmarklet with references on jquery and css files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696034/reference-from-one-js-file-to-another)

and when I try to use it on diferent sites I get different results. For example when I'm use simple css file with only one class:

```
.someClass{
color:#F00;
}
```

when I go to https://stackoverflow.com/
and use bookmarklet I get correct result (all hyperlinks are red) [image]

but when I am navigate to http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html
and use Bookmarklet I don't get correct result(hyperlinks still blue):

[image]
Why bookmarklet is work perfect in one case and so badly in another? Can I fix it?

Comment: Its probably a specificity issue.

Comment: @Musa No I try it in differnt sites. In some case it work nice but in another it doesnt work and in some cases it change only some limks? What can be wrong?

Comment: Do you know what specificity means? Try adding a !important after the colour property. `color:#F00!important;`

Answer (score 0):

See an [live example here](https://www.taosdev.com/bookmarklet-devkit/#EQCgZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQgJSoN4B02qEBuAhgE6oDOqAvKgCZIwQC2AplHAHQxlslw2AUQA2bdpxABySnACeYqRnyFClLgihQ2ZACpsAHnFqpcwEjlQwkIpGQBcqPvQCECFgAc7cEp1QBfMxVVRmYJbgALfnouEg8PDnoAYQiEEXoQSmUofwxMAG5gIA), tested and works on http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

```
(function () {
    var s = document.createElement('style')
    s.innerText = "a { color: red!important }"
    document.head.appendChild(s)
})();
```